# JAVA Eclipse "accessor" cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, eclipse, accessor

I'm writing a program and I need to create accessor/mutator methods for the variable accountID.
This is what I have so far but I can't get past this "cannot be resolved to a variable" error when I create the accessor public int getAccountID(). How do I fix this error? I've looked for about an hour through other sources but none of them have helped which is why I've resorted to posting this specific question about it. Any help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Date;

public class Account {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int accountID = 0;
        double balance = 0;
        double annualInterestRate = 0;

        Date dateCreated = new Date();

    }

    // default constructor that creates a default account
    public Account() {
        // fill this in later
    }

    // default constructor that creates an account
    public Account(int accountID, double balance, double annualInterestRate) {
        // fill this in later
    }

    // accessor for accountID
    public int getAccountID() {
        return accountID;     // THIS IS WHERE I GET MY ERROR ~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `accountID` (as well as the other variables defined in `main`) shouldn't be a local variable. It should be declared in the class level in order to be an instance variable, which will be accessible from all the non-static methods of your class.

```
public class Account {
    private int accountID = 0;
    private double balance = 0;
    private double annualInterestRate = 0;
    private Date dateCreated = new Date();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ...
    }

    ....
}
```